# Bootstrap no se me ajusta en MAC, IOs

Tags: css, bootstrap

Tengo la que siguiente situación, estoy usando **bootstrap 2.3.2** en un proyecto que tengo hecho hace varios años y ahora me esta sucediendo, que cuando lo ejecuto en **MAC pro** tengo que reducir la pantalla al 90% para que los elementos se me vean correctamente.

Esto no me esta ocurre en **Linux** ,**Windows** ya que aquí si se me encuadra sin problema. Tengo definida las etiquetas para el **responsive** y estoy usando un **container-fluid** .

Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer que en mac la versión de 2.3.2 de bootstrap se me ajuste sin problema. Gracias

**Etiquetas del responsive colocadas en el **header**:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Prueba con este *meta* en vez de con el que tienes: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0",maximun-scale=1.0>`

Comment: Puedes replicarlo con un ejemplo? o darnos un link donde lo podamos ver?. Saludos!

Comment: Estás agregando la hoja de estilos `bootstrap-responsive.css`? Dicha hoja de estilos debes agregarla junto a `bootstrap.css`.

Comment: Hice las pruebas pero el problema sigue ahora si me di cuenta que se aunmento la resolución 1440x900 a 4689x1050 se me ajusta sin problema. Si estoy colocando la hoja de estilo bootstrap.css.  Gracias

Comment: Perdon me confundi escribiendo la segundo resolución es de 1689x1050. Gracias

Answer (score -1):

En tu div principal usa la clase `.container` en vez de la clase `.container-fluid`.

La clase `.container` establece un ancho fijo que se va ajustando según el navegador. en cambio la clase `.container-fluid` siempre ocupará el 100%.

Comment: Cómo sabes que esas son las clases que está usando el OP?

Comment: Gracias pero lo que necesito es que me cubra el 100% de la pantalla.